# How to multiple touch UICollectionViewCells in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uitapgesturerecognizer

For a current project I need to be able to touch multiple UICollectionViewCells simultaneously. 
I have tried to use the UICollectionViewDelegate but I'm stuck in being able to have the Cells to be able to be touched simultaneously.

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

private let reuseIdentifier = "CustomCell"

class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

let sectionInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
let numOfPads    = 24
let numOfColumns = 4

func initConfig(){
    collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    //
    collectionView?.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyle.white
    //
    //collectionView?.backgroundView = UIView(frame: (collectionView?.frame)!)
    // lets iOS recover and respond to more than one finger touch at a time
    collectionView?.isMultipleTouchEnabled = true
    collectionView?.allowsSelection = true
    collectionView?.allowsMultipleSelection = true
    collectionView?.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    // This makes tapping on the UICollectionViewCell feel zippy
    collectionView?.delaysContentTouches = false
    // Kill any kind of scrolling
    collectionView?.isScrollEnabled = false
}

func generateRandomColor() -> UIColor {
    let redValue = CGFloat(arc4random() % 255) / 255.0
    let blueValue = CGFloat(arc4random() % 255) / 255.0
    let greenValue = CGFloat(arc4random() % 255) / 255.0

    return UIColor(red: redValue, green: greenValue, blue: blueValue, alpha: 0.5)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Register cell classes
    self.collectionView!.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    initConfig()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource

override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}


override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 24
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)

    cell.backgroundColor = generateRandomColor()

    return cell
}


// MARK: UICollectionViewDelegate

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    if let selectedItems = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems {
        if selectedItems.contains(indexPath as IndexPath) {
            collectionView.deselectItem(at: indexPath as IndexPath, animated: true)
            return false
        }
    }
    return true   
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didHighlightItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("didHighlightItemAt", indexPath)
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)! as UICollectionViewCell
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didUnhighlightItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    //print("didUnhighlightItemAt", indexPath)
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)! as UICollectionViewCell
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("didSelectItemAt", selectedCells)

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To "activate" multiple Cell selection, you just need to allow it, using the `shouldSelectItemAt` function of the `UICollectionViewDelegate`.

But in your case, we need to activate multiple Cell touch. To be able to do so, I've used UIGestureRecognizers now:

First we needed to set a `GestureRecognizer` per Cell:

```
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell", for: indexPath)

        let lpgr = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tap(gestureReconizer:)))
        lpgr.delegate = self
        cell.addGestureRecognizer(lpgr)

        return cell
    }
}
```

Then we need to receive the Cell that is tapped:

```
extension ViewController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func tap(gestureReconizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let tapLocation = gestureReconizer.location(in: self.collectionView)

        //using the tapLocation to get the indexPath
        let indexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: tapLocation)

        //now we can get the cell for item at indexPath
        let cell = self.collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath!)
        cell?.backgroundColor = generateRandomColor()

        doWhatEver(cell: cell!)
    }

    func doWhatEver(cell: UICollectionViewCell) {
        //here we do whatever like play the desired sounds of the cells.
    }

    //or we just use your random color function for fun
    func generateRandomColor() -> UIColor {
        let redValue = CGFloat(arc4random() % 255) / 255.0
        let blueValue = CGFloat(arc4random() % 255) / 255.0
        let greenValue = CGFloat(arc4random() % 255) / 255.0

        return UIColor(red: redValue, green: greenValue, blue: blueValue, alpha: 0.5)
    }
}
```

Now we are able to touch Cells simultaneously.

Comment: I'm opening Xcode right now, to provide you an code example

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: code is provided. testing it right now, but it should be working

Comment: still testing to provide the best possible result

Comment: I'm using Swift 3.0 and ```shouldSelectItemAt``` requires me to return a default boolean value.  I modified your code to look like this but I'm still not able to select two cells at the same time.  I've edited the code above to show this.

Comment: i know. i'm on it. the problem is, that the idea behind this is, that you're able to multi `select` cells

Comment: but i assume, you want to multi touch them

Comment: that's why i'm experimenting with multiple gesture recognizern at the moment

Comment: added your `func generateRandomColor() -> UIColor {`so you see, that you're able to change the colors simultan

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125805/discussion-between-david-seek-and-chris).

Comment: you're welcome. let me know if you need further assistance.

Comment: Aren't you adding multiple gesture recognisers to cells that are reused?

Comment: in his example, he'll not reuse. he has a fixed number of cells and they are constantly part of the view and will not scrolled away and scrolled back into the view